# successfully compiled custom node.js module how do I use it

Tags: node.js

I was having a lot of problems using npm to install the canvas module for node.js, so I downloaded the source code, and used visual studio 2005 to debug and correct the errors I was running into. I got it to successfully compile, but now I don't know know where to go from there in order to be able to use it in my project. Seems like it should be easy, but I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the compiled .dll file to .node and drop it in your node project.  Then just `require` it.

For example, in a folder:

```
app.js
canvas.node
...
```

In app.js:

```
var canvas = require('./canvas');
```

---

Note that in the case of the canvas module, you should have no problems using npm to install it  **if** you have a proper node native build environment ([node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp)) set up, which includes  [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3#download) and [MS Visual C++ **2010**](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-2010-express) (and for x64 builds, the [Win 7 x64 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displayLang=en&id=8279)).  VS 2005 won't work.

You'll obviously also need cario installed since canvas depends on it.